# Social link don't added in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, imageview, social-media

I'm trying to add social media links in fragment in my app. When I staring adding img_vk, `findViewById` selected red color. In empty project ImageView working fine.

```
    public class Fragment5 extends Fragment {

    ImageView img_instagram,img_vk;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        img_vk = findViewById(R.id.img_vk);
        img_vk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gotoUrl("https://vk.com/1234");
            }
        });
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment5,container,false);
        return rootView;

    }
    private void gotoUrl(String s) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should inflate the view of fragment first and then try to find your view in it.

```
public class Fragment5 extends Fragment {

    ImageView img_instagram,img_vk;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment5,container,false);
        img_vk = rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_vk);
        img_vk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gotoUrl("https://vk.com/1234");
            }
        });
       
        return rootView;

    }
    private void gotoUrl(String s) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great My Friend!